# Execute Javascript once a week

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to change a text inside a canvas circle only once a week in wordpress
The increment will always be the same.

How can I do it automatically?
I suppose it has to do with server side javascript?

Thank you,

Comment: "server side javascript" ? Are you running nodejs on your server? If it's on wordpress, it might be easier to use `php` instead

Comment: But is it possible to run javascript in a php cron? Or do you think about accomplishing this in other way?

Comment: Your statement isn't clear. Should this increment occur for every one of your users?  Should this only occur to people who came to visit your site once and again one week later? In the first case, store this info somewhere in your wordpress database and just increment it wheither with a cron or with a simple multiplication by current date - creation date. In the second case, store the user's first access time in localStorage or cookie and apply the same logic. The main idea being javascript is executed on client side, in the browser and should remain external to server, common, side.

Answer (score 1):

Your use case doesn’t seem to be a critical security issue, so it might be okay to store the information date client-side. You can save a timestamp in [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) and just do a integer comparison with something along the lines of:

```
var weekInMilliseconds = 7*24*60*60*1000; // == 604800000 ms
var lastInfo = parseInt(localStorage.getItem('info'), 10); // either NaN or timestamp

if(isNaN(lastInfo))
    lastInfo = 0; // 1970, mind you

// if last info showed earlier than one week ago:
if(lastInfo < (Date.now() - weekInMilliseconds)){
    localStorage.setItem('info',Date.now()); // set info date now
    alert('Information or action (once a week)'); // display your information
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store the first time a page is loaded in your cookie or localstorage and then each time the page os loaded do a check with the current date.

With that said you should probably do this kind of things on the server side and retrive it on the client because if you're doing it in browser you have no control or replication on multiple devices

Comment: Can you explain me a little more how can I do so? Thank you

Comment: look at the answer above xD

Answer (score 0):

You can set a localstorage item to have constance of the last update:

```
var date = new Date();
localStorage.setItem("last update", date.getDate());
```

And check the day on load:

```
window.onload = function(){
  var date = new Date();

  if(date.getDate() >= parseInt(localStorage.getItem("lastupdate"))+7){
    // RUN YOUR CODE
  }
}
```

Comment: But this will be executed everytime a user enters to my page, so the localstorage will always be rewritten, won't be?

Comment: No, you have to put the first code statment in the WHATEVERYOUWANTTODO function, so the localstorage just updates when the script has been ran